# Eigen used by catkin is different from rosbuild's one?

Tags: navigation, eigen, rosmake, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Eigen used when catkin-making and eigen used when rosmaking are different ??

I'm trying to catkinize navigation(for Electric) to use it on Groovy.

**When I use non-catkinized navigation(navigation for electric), I have no error and it works well.

However, with a catkinized navigation(this is not navigation-groovy-devel-catkinized), I have error as followings even if header files, cpp files are shared.**

`` move_base: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:69: Eigen::internal::plain_array::plain_arry() [with T = float, int Size = 4, int MatrixOrArrayOptions = 0]: Assertion `(reinterpret_cast(array) & 0xf) == 0 && "this assertion explained here: " "http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html" " **** READ THIS WEB PAGE !! ****"' failed. ``

navigation-groovy-devel-catkinized and branch "fix-97" which is reported that the bug was fixed also show the same error.
So I'm trying to catkinize and use old version navigation.

My questions are followings.

- Eigen used when catkin-making and eigen used when rosmaking are different ??
- How do I use eigen which doesn't cause the above error ??
- Is it caused by different version g++ ?? If so, how do I avoid this problem ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/82576/eigen-used-by-catkin-is-different-from-rosbuild%27s-one-?/) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2013-09-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jochen Hemming](https://answers.ros.org/users/11906/jochen-hemming/) on 2014-02-18**:
I have the same problem with a time of flight camera driver. Did you already find a fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Eigen is used as a system dependency so you get whatever version of Eigen is installed with your version of Ubuntu.  If you are using different versions of Ubuntu you will potentially get different versions of Eigen.

The link in the error message appears broken, I think the equivilant page is here: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1